# org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3MergeEventListener missing after upgrading from Hibernate 3 to 4.3.9

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb

I am trying to upgrade from Hibernate 3.6.10 to 4.3.9 (and JPA 2.0 to 2.1).

Some code in my application uses the `org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3MergeEventListener` class, which used to be in the  hibernate-entitymanager jar, but is missing from the 4.3.9 version. From what I can tell, it was removed as of 4.3, but I can't find any information on why this might be or what I should do to work around it. I thought perhaps it was moved to another jar or package (as many other classes were) but I can't find it anywhere.

EDIT: According to the [Hibernate user documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.3/pdf/Hibernate_EntityManager_User_Guide/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform-4.3-Hibernate_EntityManager_User_Guide-en-US.pdf), this class is supposed to be included in version 4.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like this class (and a lot of the other EJB stuff) has been renamed and moved around. I was able to replace instances of `org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3MergeEventListener` (which was located in the hibernate-entitymanager jar in version 3.6.10) with `org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener` (which is actually located in the hibernate-core jar in version 4.3.9), and it works.

The class is still, however, listed in the Hibernate 4.3 documentation under the old name/package.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add `hibernate-entitymanager.jar`. you can find this jar [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhibernateentitymanager423finaljar.htm)

Comment: Won't that conflict with `hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.9.Final.jar`? They contain a lot of the same classes, but the 4.3.9 version is missing `org.hibernate.ejb.event.*`.

Comment: I did try this, but as expected there were problems when using incompatible versions. As a result I encountered the same problem as in this thread (null pointer when trying to persist): [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058583/nullpointerexception-when-persisting-entity)